# .equals() when class constructor is created & comparing of simple string

Tags: java, equals

I had made a program on `.equals()` in java & having some conceptual problem when I saw some of the online videos on youtube & searched about this thing but not got proper explanation. So guys help me with that thing.

Thanks.

```
package Practice;

public class StringManipulation11 {

    StringManipulation11(String s) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "Good";
        String s1 = "Good";
        String s2 = "Morning";

        String t = new String("Good");
        String t1 = new String("Good");
        String t2 = new String("Morning");

        StringManipulation11 sm = new StringManipulation11("Good");
        StringManipulation11 sm1 = new StringManipulation11("Good");

        System.out.println(s.equals(s1));// true because check content
        System.out.println(s.equals(s2));// false content not match

        System.out.println(t.equals(t1));// true because check content
        System.out.println(s.equals(t));// true because check content

        System.out.println(sm.equals(sm1));// false, but not getting the reason
                                            // why it is false

        /*
         * In this case also the content is same but not getting the proper
         * conclusion why it is false & it is false then why i am getting true
         * in "System.out.println(t.equals(t1))" in this condtion.
         */

        System.out.println(s.equals(sm));

    }
}
```

Comment: Need to see what StringManipulation does

Comment: Just a class buddy

Comment: Well, that's the reason, buddy

Answer (score 4):

> In this case, also the content is same but not getting the proper conclusion why it is false & it is false then why I am getting true in `System.out.println(t.equals(t1))` in this condition.

The class `String` has an implementation of `equals` (and `hashcode`) which compares the two objects character by character. Your class does not have an implementation of these methods, so it uses the implementation it has inherited from `Object`, which compares the references, i.e. for it to be true, the instances need to be the *same*.

That's an important distinction to get your head around, *same* means these two references are pointing to the exact same instance. And *equals* means that they are either the same or have equivalent content, but it is up to you to define how the content is compared, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java).

Comment: To put it in layman's terms: 

You never said what it MEANS to be "equal" when comparing the two objects.

Answer (score 0):

StringManipulation11 is extend object, if you didn't override the `equals method` the default method is

```
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (this == obj);
    }
```

you can compare the equals method in `String`

```
public boolean equals(Object var1) {
        if(this == var1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if(var1 instanceof String) {
                String var2 = (String)var1;
                int var3 = this.value.length;
                if(var3 == var2.value.length) {
                    char[] var4 = this.value;
                    char[] var5 = var2.value;

                    for(int var6 = 0; var3-- != 0; ++var6) {
                        if(var4[var6] != var5[var6]) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition of the `equals` method in the String class (Java 8):

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject)
Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only
if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same
sequence of characters as this object.
```

Which means that this method returns true if and only if both Strings represent the same sequence of characters.

In your case you have defined a new class `StringManipulation11` which by default uses the `equals` method of the `Object` class. And this is its definition:

```
The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating
possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null 
reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y 
refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).
```

In your example you have defined two different objects `sm` and `sm1`. These variables refer to DIFFERENT objects and this is why the `equals` method returns false.